# How to change CSS on an input type=text if it has duplicate entries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four text boxes [00:00][00:10][00:20][00:00]

code looks like:

```
<div class="schedules">
     <input type="text" class="schedentry1" id="sch1" value="00:00">
</div>
<div class="schedules">
     <input type="text" class="schedentry1" id="sch2" value="00:00">
</div>
...
```

I am looping through each box checking for duplicates (in above case dupes are [00:00]

How do I now put a red border around the div to alert user that they are dupes?

Thank you

```
$('#row1 .schedentry1').each(function() { 
    times.push( $( this ).val() ); 
});


function find_duplicates(input) {
        duplicates = [input]
        var i, j;
              for (i = 0, j = input.length; i < j; i++) {
                  if (duplicates.indexOf(input[i]) === -1) {
                      if (input.indexOf(input[i], i + 1) !== -1) {
                          duplicates.push(input[i]);

                      }
                  }
              }

              console.log("test " + duplicates[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Post your current code where you loop.

Comment: $('#row1 .schedentry1').each(function()
        {
            times.push( $( this ).val() );
        });

Comment: function find_duplicates(input) {
            duplicates = [input]
            var i, j;
                  for (i = 0, j = input.length; i < j; i++) {
                      if (duplicates.indexOf(input[i]) === -1) {
                          if (input.indexOf(input[i], i + 1) !== -1) {
                              duplicates.push(input[i]);

                          }
                      }
                  }

                  console.log("test " + duplicates[1]);
        }

Comment: sorry I can't seem to format it as code

Comment: click `edit` underneath your question and add it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ary = [];
$('.schedentry1').each(function () {
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), ary) > -1) {
        $('.schedentry1[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').addClass('dupe')
    }
    ary.push($(this).val())
})
```

```js
var ary = [];
$('.schedentry1').each(function () {
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), ary) > -1) {
        $('.schedentry1[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').addClass('dupe')
    }
    ary.push($(this).val())
})
```

```css
.dupe {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="schedules">
    <input type="text" class="schedentry1" id="sch1" value="00:00">
</div>
<div class="schedules">
    <input type="text" class="schedentry1" id="sch2" value="00:10">
</div>
<div class="schedules">
    <input type="text" class="schedentry1" id="sch3" value="00:20">
</div>
<div class="schedules">
    <input type="text" class="schedentry1" id="sch4" value="00:00">
</div>
```

Comment: On my page, the boxes default to [00:00][00:00][00:00][00:00]
I enter the different values click on a button and it checks the row for duplicate entries and should use the css .dupe and show me the dupes.

Comment: I can't seem to get the logic working right. It adds the .dupe for all rows.

Comment: Are you using my code in your check when you click the button you mention?

Comment: Yes I am checking when clicking button.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working since you can see in the example it does. Can you update the question or link to the page?

Comment: Please note, I am editing the [00:00][00:00][00:00][00:00] and changing their values.
So if I edit them like
[00:10][00:22][13:00][00:10] and click the submit button, the 2 text boxes with [00:10] should be bordered with red.
When I do it with your code, all 4 boxes are getting a red border
Thanks

Comment: Are you calling the code on the change, keyup, keydown, keypress, or blur event(s)?

Comment: $("#submit").on('click', function () {}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67260/discussion-between-motti10-and-j08691).

Comment: How about you create a jsFiddle example of what you say it's doing?

Comment: I am all set. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can just check inside the `loop` if a selector brings back more than 1 result:

```
$('#row1 .schedentry1').each(function() { 
    var value = this.value;
    times.push( value ); 

    //Get elems that match this value
    var matchingElems = $("#row1 .schedentry1[value=" + value + "]");

    //If more than 1 element returned, add a red border to both
    if (matchingElems.length > 1) {
        matchingElems.css("border","1px solid red");
    }
});
```

Comment: This is adding all entries [10:00][20:00][00:00][00:00] to the matchingElems and not just the dupes.
All four objects are showing a rec border

Answer (score 1):

Use an object to keep track of which values have been seen before.

```
var values = {}

  // in loop
  if (values[this.value]) {
    $(this).addClass('error')
  } else {
    values[this.value] = true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do data

**With Loop and Array**

```
records=[];
 $('.schedentry1').each(function () {
if (records.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
    $(this).parent("div").css("border","1px solid red");
}
records.push($(this).val())
 })
```

**With selectors**(jquery itself still loops through selectors and returns array)

Since you have only 4 values you can do this with selectors also

```js
$('.schedentry1[value="00:00"]:gt(0),.schedentry1[value="00:10"]:gt(0),.schedentry1[value="00:20"]:gt(0)')
.parent("div")
.css("border","1px solid red");
```

```css
div{margin:10px 0px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="schedules">
    <input type="text" class="schedentry1" id="sch1" value="00:00"/>
</div>
<div class="schedules">
    <input type="text" class="schedentry1" id="sch2" value="00:00"/>
</div>
    <div class="schedules">
    <input type="text" class="schedentry1" id="sch1" value="00:10"/>
</div>
<div class="schedules">
    <input type="text" class="schedentry1" id="sch2" value="00:10"/>
</div>
<div class="schedules">
    <input type="text" class="schedentry1" id="sch1" value="00:20"/>
</div>
<div class="schedules">
    <input type="text" class="schedentry1" id="sch2" value="00:20"/>
</div>
```